# name of the next xml tag

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How would I get name of the next xml tag ?

```
<SUBSCRIBER>
    <Anumber>639093700012</Anumber>
    <FirstCallDate>20090612124207</FirstCallDate>
    <SetyCode>TNT</SetyCode>
    <PARSETAG>parseind</PARSETAG>
    <Status>ACT</Status>
    <RoamIndicator>1</RoamIndicator>
    <PreloadCode>P1.0</PreloadCode>
</SUBSCRIBER>
```

The following code starts parsing from tag PARSETAG and prints the next xml tag value. How would I get next xml tag name ?

For example, the below code prints ACT, 1, P1.0 tag values but I need the respective tag names also.

```
    <xsl:template match="SUBSCRIBER/*" mode="RULE_DA_TEST">
        <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::PARSETAG">
                    <!-- some logic here -->
        <xsl:variable name="tagname" select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="tagvalue" select="????????????????"/>
                    <!-- some logic here -->  
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: <xsl:variable name="tagvalue" select="name(following-sibling::node()[1])"/> is the answer. Correct me if I am wrong or suggest other if any.

Answer (score 1):

Your test selects only the nodes that have a `PARSETAG` as preceding siblings (it excludes `PARSETAG`). So your nodes are `Status`, `RoamIndicator` and `PreloadCode`. If you want the data from these three nodes, don't use `following-sibling` to extract your data otherwise you will exclude `Status`. When the context node is `Status`, the expression `following-sibling:node()` will select the node *after* `Status`, and you will only get `RoamIndicator` and `PreloadCode` as a result.

So to get name and value of all sibling nodes after `PARSETAG` you should use:

```
<xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::PARSETAG">
    <xsl:variable name="tagname" select="name(.)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tagvalue" select="."/>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

`following-sibling::*/name()` gives you a sequence of strings with the names of the following sibling elements.

Comment: I think my question was bit unclear. I want to save next tag name and its value in variable's for processing. Please see my question that was just edited.

Comment: I think, I got it,                                           <xsl:variable name="tagvalue" select="name(following-sibling::node()[1])"/>

Comment: If you are looking for the name of the next `element` node then I would use `name(following-sibling::*[1])` as `(following-sibling::node()[1]` might select a `text` node or comment node.